# Create ref on struct

Tags: c#, struct, reference, ref

I want to send a reference to a struct to a form. Then I need to store the reference so I can do changes to a member of that struct before the form is closed. Here's the code:

```
struct mystruct
{
    public int myvar;
}

public partial class myForm : Form
{
    private mystruct refonstruct;
    
    public myForm(ref mystruct ms)
    {
        // refonstruct will be a copy, not a reference :-(
        refonstruct = ms;
        // how can I get a reference instead?
    }

    public myForm_FormClosing()
    {
        // since refonstruct is not a reference the next line will not change foostruct 
        refonstruct.myvar = 17;
    }
}

public void foo()
{
    mystruct foostruct;
    foostruct.myvar = 0;
    using(myForm f= new myForm(ref foostruct))f.ShowDialog();
    // here foostruct, myvar will still be 0 since refonstruct is a copy not a reference
}
```

Passing a struct as refernce in the constructor is not the problem. If I would be able to do changes to the member of the struct there (ms.myvar = 17) it would work. But I can only apply the changes before closing the dialog. In case I could use a class instead all would be no problem, I know, but I for so many reasons (e.g. existing huge project, file format, etc.) I cannot. Summary: Is there a way to store a reference to a struct in a member variable? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why are you using structs in the first place? `struct` types have limited and specific purposes, and being a general data-transfer-object or mutable state store is not one of them.

Comment: I use struct in the first place because it already exists in the project and is also serialized

Answer (score 0):

If you want forms to share data a struct is not the correct approach to use. Structs are value types, and stored in the context where they are used. This would be the stack frame of `foo()` in this case. Since `myForm` is a class, it can have a longer lifetime than `foo()`. So if it could store a reference, that reference might be invalid and refer to some random position on the callstack, and that is just not allowed.

The easiest option is to just change `mystruct` to a class.

An alternative is to introduce a wrapper around the struct:

```
    public class Ref<T>
    {
        public T Value { get; set; }
        public Ref(T value) => Value = value;
    }
```

That way your struct can be immutable, and you would just replace the entire struct when it needs to change. You can also add an event that is raised when the value is set, to let any form know if it needs to update itself to show the updated value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am aware of the stack/heap problem. As I said, I cannot change the struct to a class since this would affect the whole project. Anyway, I just want to make sure that there's not a simple solution to my problem...

Comment: @M. Enke It sounds like you have a serious architectural problem if you cannot change anything. "Affecting the whole project" does not mean it cannot or should not be done, but you need to weight the advantages of the change with the risks.

Comment: Actually it is not a big problem: I can also create a public property in the form, it is just not very elegant. Since the struct is also stored in a file, I cannot change it to a class without dealing all the file reading stuff.

Comment: @M. Enke If you are using a decent serialization library I would expect changing struct->class to require little or no changes. If you are using BinaryFormatter for serialization I would recommend switching to just about anything else. I would be quite careful when using the same types for serialization and the rest of the program, precisely because it limits how you can change your types.